# Parameter count mismatch when invoking control with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, delegates, invoke, multithreading

I use a thread to execute some process on a machine. Eventually, the progress is reported back in an other thread. To update the GUI with the status of the process, I use a delegate like this:

```
public delegate void UpdateProgressDelegate(string description, int scriptnumber);
public void UpdateProgress(string description, int scriptnumber) {
    if (treeView.InvokeRequired) {
        treeView.Invoke(new UpdateProgressDelegate(UpdateProgress), description, scriptnumber);
        return;
    }
    // Update the treeview
}
```

And to call this delegate I use:

```
form.UpdateProgress("Ready", 3);
```

When the Invoke is called, I get a TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
I thought I could fix this by placing the string and int parameters in a single object like this:

```
public delegate void UpdateProgressDelegate(object[] updateinfo);
public void UpdateProgress(object[] updateinfo) {
    string description = (string) updateinfo[0];
    int scriptnumber = (int) updateinfo[1];
    if (treeView.InvokeRequired) {
        treeView.Invoke(new UpdateProgressDelegate(UpdateProgress), new object[] { description, scriptnumber });
        return;
    }       
    // Update the treeview
}
```

And to call it I use:

```
form.UpdateProgress(new object[] {"Ready", 3});
```

But this doesn't work either. I keep getting the same TargetParameterCountException. Any ideas how I could fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the AddScript method declared? Or did you just confuse UpdateProgress with AddScript in the code above?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Whoops, I did confuse them, AddScript is a completely different function! I will update my post, the problem and exception is still the same tho.

Comment: @Tigran scriptnumber is an integer, I will update my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say: do it the easy way:

```
treeView.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    UpdateProgress(description, scriptnumber);
});
```

or (equally):

```
treeView.Invoke((MethodInvoker) () => UpdateProgress(description, scriptnumber));
```

This gives you static-checking at the compiler, and IIRC `MethodInvoker` is checked explicitly, and called with `Invoke()` rather than `DynamicInvoke()`, making it faster too.

---

Re why it doesn't work; in your example with:

```
public delegate void UpdateProgressDelegate(object[] updateinfo);
```

you are actually passing two parameters; to disambiguate and pass a single array to a `params` here, you need to double-wrap it:

```
treeView.Invoke(new UpdateProgressDelegate(UpdateProgress),
    new object[] { new object[] {description, scriptnumber }});
```

Basically, the outer array is the "array of all the parameters", which contains a single element, which is the array that we wan't to pass as the first parameter (`updateinfo`).

Comment: Ah, that's why! But is there an advantage using your solution instead of the solution Thomas gave (by using a delegate function), except for performance? Or are there just two ways to achieve the same thing?

Comment: @Carlito if you mean "compared to the double-wrap" (i.e. the bit at the bottom of my answer) - that will perform identically to the more specific delegate approach; if you mean "compared to the anonymous method" (i.e. the bit at the top of my answer) - then: static type checking at the compiler! It won't let you use invalid parameters, etc. It also avoids the need for a confusing extra delegate type.

Comment: Alright, thank you for helping me out. I accepted your answer!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public delegate void UpdateProgressDelegate(string description, int scriptnumber);
public void UpdateProgress(string description, int scriptnumber) {
    if (treeView.InvokeRequired) {
        treeView.Invoke(new UpdateProgressDelegate(UpdateProgress), new object[] { description, scriptnumber });
        return;
    }
    // Update the treeview
}
```